# Assigning Unique Colors To Multiple Lines on a Graph

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, legend

I found this R tutorial that I would like to modify : https://stephens999.github.io/fiveMinuteStats/simulating_discrete_chains_1.html

In this tutorial, the author is showing how to plot the state transitions of a Markov Chain - and the Markov Chain is being simulated several times.

```
# simulate discrete Markov chains according to transition matrix P
run.mc.sim <- function( P, num.iters = 50 ) {
  
  # number of possible states
  num.states <- nrow(P)
  
  # stores the states X_t through time
  states     <- numeric(num.iters)

  # initialize variable for first state 
  states[1]    <- 1

  for(t in 2:num.iters) {
    
    # probability vector to simulate next state X_{t+1}
    p  <- P[states[t-1], ]
    
    ## draw from multinomial and determine state
    states[t] <-  which(rmultinom(1, 1, p) == 1)
  }
  return(states)
}

P <- t(matrix(c( 1/3, 2/3,   0,   0,  0,   0,   0,   0,
                 1/3, 1/3, 1/3,   0,  0,   0,   0,   0,
                   0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3,  0,   0,   0,   0,
                   0,   0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3,  0,   0,   0,
                   0,   0,   0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3,  0,   0,
                   0,   0,   0,   0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3,  0,
                   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3,
                   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 2/3, 1/3), nrow=8, ncol=8))

# I am changing these numbers compared to the initial distirbution

num.chains     <- 100
num.iterations <- 100
chain.states <- matrix(NA, ncol=num.chains, nrow=num.iterations)
for(c in seq_len(num.chains)){

  chain.states[,c] <- run.mc.sim(P)
}

 matplot(chain.states, type='l', lty=1, col=1:5, ylim=c(0,9), ylab='state', xlab='time')
    abline(h=1, lty=3)
    abline(h=8, lty=3)
```

- Is it possible to assign each of these lines a unique color?
- Is it possible to add a legend to this graph such that the legend does not interfere with the graph itself?

I tried to add a legend, but it ended up blocking the graph:

```
#I only showed for 8 chains...I don't think it's possible to show for all 100 chains without interfering with the graph, regardless of how the legend is placed

legend('topright', c('chain.1', 'chain.2', 'chain.3', 'chain.4', 'chain.5', 'chain.6','chain.7','chain.8'), lty=1, col=1:8)
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

- Is it possible to assign each line a different color?
- Is there some way to show a legend (even for 10-15 lines) in such a way that the legend does not interfere with the graph?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a palette, e.g. built in `rainbow`. However 100 colors may not be very distinguishable.

```
clr <- rainbow(num.chains)  ## create `num.chains` colors
matplot(chain.states, type='l', lty=1, col=clr, ylim=c(0, 9), 
        ylab='state', xlab='time')
abline(h=1, lty=3)
abline(h=8, lty=3)
```

Comment: Thank you! I agree : 100 might be too many. Even if there were just 10 colors, I was still looking for an automatic way to assign each line a different color. Thank you so much!

Comment: @antonoyaro8 Welcome. You could also consider `?heat.colors` or similar, the range is restricted, but you could give the colors meaning by changing gradient according to number of iterations, or the attribute you're interested in, respectively. Or use groups.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any idea on how to put the legend so that it doesn't cut the graph? Can you force the legend outside the graph? Thank you!

Comment: I am looking at http://applied-r.com/r-graphics-heat-colors/ - is this what you were talking about? If you have time, could you please show an example as to how heat.colors can be used in this graph? I am currently trying it myself! Thanks so much!

Comment: @antonoyaro8 Just replace `rainbow` with `heat.colors`, the syntax is similar. For the legend try `legend('bottom', paste0('chain.', 1:8), lty=1, col=1:8,bty='n', ncol=4, cex=.75)`.